# How to calculate actual load in a vehicle

Tags: r

follogwing problem:

I have some sensors in vehicles which counting up when passengers enter the vehicle and counting up when passengers leaving the vehicle.

for example:

```
tibble::tibble(
  station = c(1,2,3,4),
  passenger_increment_in = c(22, 23, 25, 25),
  passenger_increment_out = c(50, 50, 50, 53)
) %>% 
  mutate(passenger_in = passenger_increment_in - lag(passenger_increment_in),
         passenger_out = passenger_increment_out - lag(passenger_increment_out))
```

```
# A tibble: 4 × 5
  station passenger_increment_in passenger_increment_out passenger_in passenger_out
    <dbl>                  <dbl>                   <dbl>        <dbl>         <dbl>
1       1                     22                      50           NA            NA
2       2                     23                      50            1             0
3       3                     25                      50            2             0
4       4                     25                      53            0             3
```

This sensors counting up until they are resetet.
So I calculate with the `lag()` function the actual entering and leaving passengers.

But how to calculate the actual load at the acutal station in the vehicle?

So the output should be:

```
# A tibble: 4 × 6
  station passenger_increment_in passenger_increment_out passenger_in passenger_out passenger_load
    <dbl>                  <dbl>                   <dbl>        <dbl>         <dbl>          <dbl>
1       1                     22                      50           NA            NA             NA
2       2                     23                      50            1             0              1
3       3                     25                      50            2             0              3
4       4                     25                      53            0             3              0
```

I know what to calculate but no how to manage this in R :/

I hope someone is able to help me quick

Answer (score 1):

We could do it like this: Main feature is to use `cumsum` after replacing the NA to 0:

```
library(tidyverse)

tibble::tibble(
  station = c(1,2,3,4),
  passenger_increment_in = c(22, 23, 25, 25),
  passenger_increment_out = c(50, 50, 50, 53)
) %>% 
  mutate(passenger_in = passenger_increment_in - lag(passenger_increment_in),
         passenger_out = passenger_increment_out - lag(passenger_increment_out)) %>% 
  mutate(passenger_load = (passenger_in + -(passenger_out)),
         passenger_load = cumsum(replace_na(passenger_load, 0)))
```

```
station passenger_increment_in passenger_increment_o~ passenger_in passenger_out passenger_load
    <dbl>                  <dbl>                  <dbl>        <dbl>         <dbl>          <dbl>
1       1                     22                     50           NA            NA              0
2       2                     23                     50            1             0              1
3       3                     25                     50            2             0              3
4       4                     25                     53            0             3              0
>
```